# OWI robotic arm with flick hat

Tags: python

I am trying to use flick-hat to control my OWI robotic arm with usb kit. I followed the instruction in this website https://www.hackster.io/pi-supply/raspberry-pi-as-a-robotic-arm-controller-with-flick-hat-412827 but after install everything in my raspberry pi , I try to test my robot by using 'sudo python testRobotArm.py'. And I get following

```
'Init'ing RobotArm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testRobotArm.py", line 10, in <module>
    arm = RobotArm.RobotArm()
  File "/home/pi/armcontrol/RobotArm.py", line 27, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Could not connect to Robotic Arm USB device. Is the arm connected properly? Perhaps you're not running as root?")
ValueError: Could not connect to Robotic Arm USB device. Is the arm connected properly? Perhaps you're not running as root?
Stopping RobotArm
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ctrl_transfer'" in <bound method RobotArm.__del__ of <RobotArm.RobotArm instance at 0x76b9dfa8>> ignored'
```

I think I connect the arm correctly and set up everything, and i checked lsusb that the usb is detected asBus 001 Device 004: ID 1267:0001 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc

Is there any solution?